# Dynamic Design for History Report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating history report for my current project. Since its confidential i will explain
with Student Subject example. Student, Subject and StudentSubject are three tables and _Audit are their respective Audit tables & Audit Trail info will be stored in _ Audit Tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AudRel](
    [AudId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AudTableName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [AudFieldName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [AudFieldID] [varchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AuditRel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AudId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student](
    [StudentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StudentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student_Audit](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentSubject](
    [SSID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentID] [int] NULL,
    [SubjectID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentSubject] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SSID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentSubject_Audit](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SSID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StudentID] [int] NULL,
    [SubjectID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Subject](
    [SubjectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SubjectName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Subject] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SubjectID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Subject_Audit](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SubjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubjectName] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AudRel] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[AudRel] ([AudId], [AudTableName], [AudFieldName], [AudFieldID]) VALUES (1, N'Student', N'StudentName', N'StudentID')
INSERT [dbo].[AudRel] ([AudId], [AudTableName], [AudFieldName], [AudFieldID]) VALUES (2, N'Subject', N'SubjectName', N'SubjectID')


SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AudRel] OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Student] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([StudentID], [StudentName]) VALUES (1, N'Alex')
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([StudentID], [StudentName]) VALUES (2, N'DSouza')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Student] OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[StudentSubject] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[StudentSubject] ([SSID], [StudentID], [SubjectID]) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[StudentSubject] ([SSID], [StudentID], [SubjectID]) VALUES (2, 2, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[StudentSubject] ([SSID], [StudentID], [SubjectID]) VALUES (3, 2, 2)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[StudentSubject] OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Subject] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[Subject] ([SubjectID], [SubjectName]) VALUES (1, N'English')
INSERT [dbo].[Subject] ([SubjectID], [SubjectName]) VALUES (2, N'Mathematics')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Subject] OFF
```

I use below dynamic script and it perfects works for indepedent tables like Student and SUbject but this design
doesnt work for StudentSubject as it is a relational table
how to dynamically fit this table to the existing design, any suggestion . Do i need re design the Audit Relational table, please advice

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100),@FieldName VARCHAR(100),@FieldID VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @TableName = [AudTableName]
, @FieldName=[AudFieldName]
, @FieldID=[AudFieldID] 
FROM [dbo].[AudRel] WHERE [AudId] = 1 -- (Ex : StudentHistory)


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
 SELECT ID,'  + @FieldID +
','  + @FieldName + ' FROM ' +  @TableName + '_Audit ' + ' WHERE ' + @FieldID + ' = ' 
+ Convert(varchar(20),@FieldID) 

print @SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Similarly do i need revise the dynamic script

Comment: I suppose the *real* question is why are you using a dynamic solution in the first place. I find that if you do need a dynamic solution like this you likely have a design flaw. The dynamic SQL you have is also wide open to injection. You are parametrising your parameters and you're not quoting your dynamic objects. What are you *really* trying to solve here, as I suspect that this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Smells like a complete design failure here. Why does `AudRel` store metadata about the other tables, and why wouldn't you have customized SQL queries for each report?

Comment: This is reduce the effort of developing 31 odd sps for 31 tables. One Dynamic SP should enough to handle them